# How to backup Ubuntu personal computer

Tags: boot, dual-boot, backup

I am quite new to Linux and just recently set up a dual boot with Windows 10. I want to make sure I have a good backup system in place before I start messing with it. The way I backed up my Windows computer was by following the instructions in this [article](https://www.pcworld.com/article/2095481/if-we-show-you-how-to-back-up-your-pc-for-free-will-you-finally-do-it.html). The article lists three steps.

First, it has you create a recovery drive that will be used in case Windows can't boot. How do I create a similar recovery drive for Ubuntu? It seems that I can do this via Clonezilla but I'm not 100% sure how. Is this step even necessary for Linux because I have already created a bootable USB to install Ubuntu?

Second, it has you create a full image backup, that you can use to restore your computer to the state it is currently in. I've read that I should use CloneZilla to do this as well. I would appreciate a link to an article or tutorial for using CloneZilla since it does not seem very intuitive to use as a beginner and I'm scared of messing up my system.

Finally, it has you do daily file backups. How do I do this with Ubuntu? Is there a built-in tool like there is with Windows?

Thank you and sorry if I'm not explaining things properly. I'm quite new to all of this.

Comment: Have you tried `man -k backup`?

Comment: Related: [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc)

Comment: @Eliah Kagan Thank you! Your comment is excellent!

Comment: Seems like a false premise: The limited choices you have to backup a Windows system is completely different from the wide-open choices to rebuild or restore an Ubuntu system. The BEST backup system is one that you understand, one that has recent and regular backups, one that you have successfully practiced restoring from, one you have notes about how to use when the emergency strikes. Beyond that, whether you use a shell command or a fancy script or a super-fancy application is purely your own taste.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*How do I create a ... recovery drive for Ubuntu? It seems that I can do this via Clonezilla but I'm not 100% sure how. Is this step even necessary for Linux because I have already created a bootable USB to install Ubuntu?* Oh, you hit the nail on the head. Since you can reinstall Ubuntu in just a few minutes, a Windows-style recovery drive is not required.

*Second, it has you create a full image backup, that you can use to restore your computer to the state it is currently in...* If you can quickly reinstall Ubuntu and the programs you use, a clone isn't necessary. Oh, you could make one with [Clonezilla](https://www.clonezilla.org/) and their [FAQ](https://drbl.org/faq/) and [tips](https://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) are mighty useful, but after you've read all of this post, you just might think you can do without. You see, clone images get big... and since you can quickly reinstall the OS and apps (more on that in a minute), you just don't need to back up everything including the kitchen sink with Ubuntu.

Reinstalling apps: If you make a list when you install an app of all the apps installed, you can reconstitute your system by just installing the fundamental Ubuntu, then installing the apps you've added since original install.  Making that list is sooo easy: just do `sudo apt list --installed > ~/all-my-programs`. (all-my-programs is just a text file you overwrite with every program addition and you could use any unique file name instead of all-my-programs.) Once you've reinstalled the basic Ubuntu, and your data from home, just do `sudo apt update && sudo apt install {insert list of apps here and don't include the curly braces}`. See here for [alternative methods to backup a list of programs and reinstall if needed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17823/how-to-list-all-installed-packages).

*Finally, it has you do daily file backups. How do I do this with Ubuntu? Is there a built-in tool like there is with Windows?* Ooodles and oodles of tools to do it; to copy to USB, another partition, another drive (internal or external), another PC, or into the cloud. The Daily backup could grab EVERTYHING or just grab everything since a predetermined event; the latter is much quicker but it depends on your having the EVERYTHING file.

Take a look at [What's a good back-up strategy for 1 desktop PC?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) , https://www.lifewire.com/backup-ubuntu-4126286, http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/backup-manager.8.html ,  and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem , then return if there's more you need to know.

PS: When Someone in the Linux world refers to an *archive*, that's a compressed file which has many files inside it, like a ZIP file. It could be a complete backup, a chunk of a backup, or a buncha files you're sending elsewhere.